# Center Video Play Button Bar under VideoView Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

When I hover over my video, a navigation bar appears but is not centered....any ideas how to center?  Here is my xml and screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#00ffffff">
  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/video_close_btn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/videoPlayer"
    android:src="@drawable/close_button"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#00ffffff">
  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/video_close_btn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/close_button"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```